# error at autorelease when prototype cell uses date from plist?

Tags: ios, plist, autorelease

when I populate my tableview with a custom cell when it is using just STRING from the plist I have no problem. but when i try to populate

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [partyTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

partyTime in the plist was set to "date" format. it would crash. if i changed the date to "string" and no problem.
if i leave it as date i get an error at Main.m autoreleasepool

```
@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([BaliPartyAppDelegate class]));
    }
```

do i need to release NSDate? and Image? how?

this is my code so far

```
 NSArray *parties;
    NSArray *searchResults;
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *thumbnails;
    NSArray *partyTime;
}
@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
   // parties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Snoop Dog", @"AVICII", @"Frenzal Rhomb", @"Someone else", @"Cool Band", @"Lady Boys",  nil];
    // Find out the path of recipes.plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"parties" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    parties = [dict objectForKey:@"PartyName"];
    thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"];
    partyTime = [dict objectForKey:@"PartyTime"];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [parties count];

    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PartyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   }

   if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   } else {
       cell.textLabel.text = [parties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.detailTextLabel.text = [partyTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       //cell.imageView.image = [thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ARC (since I don't see any other calls to "`release`" in your code snippet), don't worry about releasing anything.  The crash you're seeing has to do with what you are assigning to the cell's label "`.text`" property. [The "`.text`" property of a UILabel can only take a NSString object](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text).

If you pass it a NSDate object, it doesn't know what to do with it, hence the crash.

Comment: so i have to change the date to a string. then why does it crash the same for the image?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of objects you have in your "`thumbnails`" array, but they need to be "`UIImage`" objects.

Comment: what only has ".jpg"? the Thumbnails array? are you talking about the paths to the files or something else?

Comment: the array only has "jpg". what did you mean they have to be UIImage

Comment: If you want to be able to use "`cell.imageView.image =`", the "`.image`" property is expecting to see a "`UIImage`" object.  You can add UIImage objects to an array.

Comment: i'm trying this
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage thumbnails:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@”thumbnails”]];

Comment: As far as I know, UIImage doesn't have a method named `thumbnails:`, unless you're using a category I didn't know about.